# return result with another result set as an alias MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for some advice on how to build a MySQL query for the results I am looking for.

I have 2 tables tbl_features and tbl_feature_content which contain data required on my page.

tbl_features holds all the relationship info in which content is saved to the tbl_feature_content table via the parent id which is the idno of the tbl_features table.

What I am looking for is to pull a single result from the tbl_features table by its ID number and return that information in that table with also the results from the tbl_features_content table under that alias page_content.

My query to pull data from the table looks like the below.

```
SELECT 
feature_idno AS page_idno,                      
feature_title AS page_title
FROM tbl_features WHERE feature_idno = 1;
```

How do i pull all the results from tbl_feature_content WHERE feature_content_parent = feature_idno and store it as page_content.

Table Creation scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_features` (
  `feature_idno` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `feature_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feature_idno`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_feature_content` (
  `feature_content_idno` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `feature_content_parent` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `feature_content_description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feature_content_idno`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sample data:

### tbl_features

```
feature_idno   feature_title
1              Feature 1
2              Feature 2
```

### tbl_feature_content

```
feature_content_idno  feature_content_parent    feature_content_description
1                     1                         Something About The Feature 1
2                     1                         Something else About Feature 1
3                     2                         Something About The Feature 2
4                     2                         Something else About Feature 2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a61eb/2

EDIT.

What i am trying to achieve is the below.

Page_idno

-- 1

Page_title

-- Feature 1

Page_content

--Something About The Feature 1

--Something else About Feature 1

Comment: I have added the table creation scripts and the sample data to the question, as links to external sites are not always reliable.

Comment: @MarkBannister Thankyou, i wasnt sure how to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you are asking how to join tables together - like this:

```
SELECT 
feature_idno AS page_idno,                      
feature_title AS page_title,
feature_content_description AS page_content
FROM tbl_features
JOIN tbl_feature_content ON feature_idno = feature_content_parent
WHERE feature_idno = 1;
```

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a61eb/4

Comment: ill update the question with what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: that's verry close to what i'm after, is it possible to return page_idno and page
_title once and page content have as-many rows as whats in the table?

Comment: @Nathan: 
Formatting the output as displayed in the updated question is normally something you would do in the presentation layer - in this case PHP - rather than SQL.

Comment: i figured this would be the case however this answer has given me the result i was looking for before completing the rest on the presentation layer.